# SSH Mergin Folders Of The Same Name - Copying Whole Folders Structures

Tags: ssh, command

I have a module with a pretty annoying tree structure like this

```
APP  -CODE    - COMMUNITY - VB - FILE 1
                                - FILE 2        
     -DESIGN - ADMIN - DEFAULT - FILES
             - FRONTEND - DEFAULT - MORE FILES
```

The existing application already has an APP folder that shares some of the same folder names going along the tree.

The app is currently unzipped to a folder called __MACOSX, I've tried to copy the contents using a `sudo mv __MACOSX/*` command but it has said 'cannot move... Directory not empty'.

My FTP program would just add all files into their directories and ask if I wanted to overwrite any if there was a duplicate. On this new server I only have SSH access so I was wondering if there is way to copy across the folders so they will populate the directories in APP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the recursive (`-R`) flag to the `cp` command to do what you want.  For example, if I have:

```
__MACOSX/
  dir1/file1
  dir1/file2
  dir2/file3
```

And I have:

```
app/
  dir1/
```

Then I can run:

```
cp -R __MACOSX/* app/
```

And I will end up with:

```
app
app/dir1
app/dir1/file1
app/dir1/file2
app/dir2
app/dir2/file3
```

...which is what I think you want to do.